# A partition of Hypercube vertices into subcube graphs.

Tags: graph-theory

We define the vertices of a hypercube graph $H_n$ by

$$V(H_n)= \lbrace (x_1,x_2 ,\cdots , x_n) :x_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2\rbrace$$

Also we call a $m$-dimensional face of a hypercube  a $m$-dimensional subcube.

Now, let me ask my question. Is it possible to find a partition of Hypercube vertices into subcubes? I want just a partition.

Comment: Do you mean into $m$-dimensional subcubes for some given $m$?

Comment: Yes, I got my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set of binary $(n-m)$-tuples $B=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-m})\mid x_i=0,1\}$. For each $b\in B$, consider the set $H(b)$ of all vertices in $H_n$ that start with $b$. Then the subgraph induced by $H(b)$ is an $m$-dimensional hypercube, and the set of $H(b)$ over all $b\in B$ is your desired partition.